# Models/Mongoose assigning count to global variable

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to find out number of collections in model and use that number for calculation.

This is what I have

```
var gcount=Shop.count({}, ( err, count)=>{
  gcount=count;
});
```

This doesn’t give any number back.

Please let me know how I can get `gcount` to give total number of recorded in collection assigned to a variable.

Comment: The question mentioned has solution what i dont want. There main solution is to move the value back inside the query with call back. While I want to access the value outside globally. They start with same issue i am trying to solve but there solution is not what i want.